# Jumb to previous DIV being in to LI (previousElementSibling)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure,

```
<div class="one"><div>
<div class="two">
<ul>
<li data-info="1">option<li>
<li data-info="2">option<li>
<li data-info="3">option<li>
<div>
```

I can get info from LI,

`var example = jQuery(this).attr('data-info');`

but I do not kno how to go back to previous div, with class="one":

```
this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling
```

That do not work,
Thanks,

Comment: can you explain more? I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might consider using more specific Class names. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're in an LI (so the LI is `this`), and you want to get back to the parent DIV, and then to it's previous element sibling, `this.closest("div").previousElementSibling`?

Comment: Thanks James, that is the idea, ... I did no know "closest" function. I will try it.

Comment: Great! It works! ´´´this.closest("div").previousElementSibling´´´. Thank you very much!